# Sharing ASP.NET WebApp Url Inside a Network

Tags: asp.net

I thought I would just replace the localhost with my computer and it will work but it does not:

http://10.90.108.66/MyWebApplication/Default.aspx

How can I make it work so I can share the url?

Comment: Have you checked: A. Your firewall settings, B. The binding configuration on IIS?

Comment: are you using IIS or VS.Net web server? Cassini server won't accept remote connections.

Comment: Thanks! It was the IIS settings. I did that and now it has started working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cassini/the visual studio web development server?

if so, this doesn't accept remote connections, you'll have to host it in an instance of IIS